# Algebraic treatment of finding a dividend given quotient, divisor, and remainder

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a divisor of $19$ and a remainder of $11$ and a quotient of $37$ where we want to calculate the dividend, I intuitively guess that the formula is

$$\frac{x-11}{19} = 37$$

giving $714$. Was I asleep in class when they talked about a formal way to handle this issue? Can someone give a more abstract theoretical explanation? It seems `mod` should be in this somewhere.

Comment: Why would you need modular arithmetic to do this? By definition, $x=19(37)+11$.

Comment: It just seems like there might be a deeper mathematical truth to this than just what seems to be intuitive.

Comment: "It just seems like there might be a deeper mathematical truth to this than just what seems to be intuitive" Not for something this basic, there isn't.

Comment: For every integer $N $ and positive integer $d $ there are two unique integers $q $ and $r $ so that $0\le r <d $ and $N=qd+r $.  And *that* is as deep and abstract as it gets.  We can come up the algebraic terms (the integers is a unique factorization domain) but that's the end all and be all.

Comment: @fleablood: Yes, that's the number theory-esque approach I was looking for. Thanks. I come from the programming world where I instinctively want to see such things in algorithm-friendly ways.

Comment: Okay.... I thought that was intuitively obvious and not in the least bit abstract or theoretical but ...

Comment: @fleablood: What you gave before is what I just found out to be the formal theory behind Euclidean division (see Wikipedia's treatment), which is might be covered in college number theory courses. Again, this lead was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing is not math.  A number x is divided by
19 with a result of 37 and a remainder of 11.

Thus x/19 = 37 + 11/19.  So use simple algebra
to solve for x.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: As I stated above, I was looking for the Euclidean division treatment. I took a number theory course and this problem probably reminded me of it.

Comment: Number theory not needed. x = 11 (mod 19) is the hard way to solve the problem.